# How to get the scrollview position while scrolling in android

Tags: android, scrollview

We have two scrollviews in my xml , parent and child scrollviews. We want scroll the parent scrollview based on child scrollview.

The following is my xml design :

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bg" >

     <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/r1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="66dp" >

           <TextView android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is navbar"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
       </RelativeLayout>


   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/childlayout"
     android:layout_height="500dp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/r1">
       <com.example.samplescrollview.ObservableScrollView  android:id="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/r3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">

           <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </ListView>
          </RelativeLayout>

        </com.example.samplescrollview.ObservableScrollView> 
       </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

We would like to change the navbar color based on scrolling of child scrollview as we can observe in the below screen shots. For doing this we implemented the code below.

```
 public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {

                if(scrollView == scrollView1) {
                    Log.e("this is..","scrolll111111111");
                    Log.e("x="+x,"y="+y);
                    scrollView2.scrollTo(x,y);

                } else if(scrollView == scrollView2) {
                     scrollView1.scrollTo(x,y);
                    Log.e("this is..","scrolll2222222");
                    Log.e("x="+x,"y="+y);
                }
        }
```

[image]

we have also used scrollBy(), getScrollX(),getScrollY() for getting child scrollview position , but not effected in parent scrollview.

Finally, we want to change the navbar colors which is transparent by scrolling the child scrollview.

Is there any other possible ways to accomplish this task.